# Implemented keycloak on aws ec2 windows instance and it's running inside the instance only but not running outside the instance

Tags: keycloak-connect, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I'm using keycloak 15.1.1 version and 64 bit windows ec2 instance.
Downloaded RDP from aws and using RDP I logged into instance and added keycloak and mysql connecor 8.0.31  to connect keycloak with external database.
I referred from here : https://jbjerksetmyr.medium.com/how-to-setup-a-keycloak-server-with-external-mysql-database-on-aws-ecs-fargate-in-clustered-mode-9775d01cd317
I did all as here mentioned.

Note : To run keycloak they(link) used "standalone.sh" command but for windows instance :standalone" is enough.

So I ran keycloak using following command

1. command 1 : "standalone -b 172.31.35.208" This is my private ip
   It's running successfully on 172.31.35.208:9090
   Here 9090 port is mapped with 8080 so my keycloak currently running on 9090 port. But if I use this same address outside of the instance it's showing error "This site can’t be reached"
2. command 2 : "standalone -b http://ec2-35-180-74-78.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com" this is my public DNS
   [running inside instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeC7X.png)
   It's running successfully on http://ec2-35-180-74-78.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:9090/
   But if I use this same address outside of the instance it's showing error "This site can’t be reached"
   [running outside instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKrcr.png)

Note : Here -b means, I am telling to my instance that run keycloak on my private Ip or on my public DNS

I tried this : Edited inbound rules to add port 8080 and 9090 to clear traffic but it doesn't work

Anyone can help me to solve this issue

Keycloak service is not accessible from public browser but it's only on inside the instance
Help me to find out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. That issue came because of version 15. Then I used version 19 it's working now